# How can a part of url be used as variables a controller in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5.3

Working with Laravel 5.3, I'm trying to pass part of my url into a controller function dynamically with no luck so far. When a link is clicked on http://127.0.0.1:8000 page, the url becomes http://127.0.0.1:8000/politics. How can I pass the politics part into my controller function? Below is what I have in my

web.php routes file

```
Route::get('/{$category}', 'PostController@category');
```

PostController.php file

```
public function category($category)
{
    $tag = $category;

    $posts = Post::where('tag', '=', '{tag}');

    return view('post', compact('posts'));
}
```

php artisan tinker

```
Psy Shell v0.8.1 (PHP 5.6.16 ΓÇö cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> $tag = 'politics'
=> "politics"
>>> $post = App\Post::where('tag', '=', '{tag}')->get();
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#671
     all: [],
   }
>>>
```

Comment: Just to debug, does `Post::where('tag', '=', 'politics');` return anything?

Comment: Yes it returns the post with that tag as expected

Comment: So can you do `Post::where('tag', '=', $tag)` ?

Comment: Now the query works but I'm still not able to pass the url into the controller dynamically

Comment: I'm not sure why, I use pretty much the exact same code and it's working fine. What do you get in your app if you do dd($posts) instead of the return?

Comment: The query in PostController.php works well when i hard code the variable. The challenge I'm having now is how to dynamically set the variable from the url. Make sense?

Comment: Yep, that's why I asked about doing the `dd()` instead of the return. Your code should work fine, so what is returned when you go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/politics in your browser?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134504/discussion-between-mena-and-andy-holmes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after reviewing the code and putting a small demo together locally there is only *one* minor reason as to why this is failing.

`{varName}` variables are already recognised as a variable so you don't need to define it as `$varName` like you are currently (`{$category}`)

The following code should give you a working example:

Create a controller called `DemoController`.

Inside this file put the following:

```
public function demo($category) 
{
    dd($category); 
}
```

Inside your `routes\web.php` route file add the following line"

`Route::get('/mena/{category}', 'DemoController@demo');`

Now, when you go to `www.website.com/mena/politics` you should see it print `politics` to the screen.

Comment: Thanks a million for your time and patience. Code has been corrected and issue resolved

Comment: Absolutely anytime @Mena